# I sat primary key on name varchar it accepts one null value

Tags: sql-server

I sat primary key on name varchar it accepts one null value

It acts like unique constraint.

What's the problem?

Comment: Who says there is a problem?  A primary key has to be unique for it to be meaningful, hence you can't have duplicates.

Comment: Name varchar(400) primary key,it accepts one null value. Try in mssql

Comment: @ImtiyazAhmadbhat, as it was said already, a *primary key* is by definition unique. Hence you cannot have two rows with the same values, whether they are the same strings, or nulls. If you want to have an index on this column, create a PK on another column, and just index your varchar column using filtered indexes (that allow to filter out nulls)

Answer (score 1):

I think you;re missing some details in ques but if you set any column to PK it doesn't allow null values into it.

But, Usually we will not set Primary Key constraint on anything(name column here) which are having a meaning in the system and instead have something like ID or GUID as primary key.

Comment: Name varchar(400) primary key,it accepts one null value. Try in mssql

Comment: tried..

Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Name', table 'Sample.dbo.MyTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Wait wait I m passing like this '' no space between them

Comment: @ImtiyazAhmadbhat empty string is not the same as null. The primary key must uniquely identify the row and so be unique.

Comment: then that's not a Null value, it allows empty value. But i would recommend you to use something like ID or GUID as primary key instead of Name column as suggested in my ans.

Comment: Igot it.Thank u all for your help.I love u